# Laravel 5.2 Prevent user form login when he is blocked

Tags: php, laravel

This is my login function in AuthenticatesUsers.php

```
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->login($request);


if (Auth::validate(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'block' => 1])) {
            return redirect("/")->withErrors('User blocked');
            }

    }
```

I set 1 in blocked field in DB ant still let's me login. Can u tell me why ?

Comment: Are you modifying the `AuthenticatesUsers.php` file in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @Bogdan

Comment: Anything in the `vendor` directory should be **off limits** to editing, because if you update Laravel then those changes will be overwritten on the update. So just to get this right so I can provide an answer, are you trying to block a user from logging in if they have the `block` column set to `1` in the `users` table?

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you essentially need to do is override the `getCredentials` method in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. As stated in a previous comment, you do not want to edit anything in the `vendor` directory.

Please take a look at [this blog post](http://www.chrisgmyr.com/2015/12/how-to-alter-laravels-quickstart-authentication-process/) to see how I've done something similar.

Comment: When I do this: `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers {
     getCredentials as traitGetCredentials;
}`

Comment: I get this: `syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';'`

Comment: is that within your class? It looks like you put it above your class. Take a look at the full solution at the bottom of the post.

Comment: This is how my code looks right now: http://pastebin.com/wvuHhcCz

This is the error now: `Trait method getLogin has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController`

Comment: Ah, you should be using `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` instead of `AuthenticatesUsers` (I was not using the registration option in my post). So like this: http://pastebin.com/dd0Kh1Na

Comment: How to redirect now with sepcific error if blocked?

Comment: By default Laravel will just return a message staying that the credentials used are not valid, but if you want to override the message you can override the `sendFailedLoginResponse` method.

Comment: Can I overide this in vendor ?

Comment: No, you definitely do not want to do anything in the `vendor` directory. Once you do a composer update, all of your changes will be lost. Since you are overriding another trait method, you can put the method in your `AuthController`. Here is a [good article](http://www.phpzag.com/overloading-and-overriding-in-php/) on overriding methods